# Offline phonegap build web app stay on page when php file can't be reached from server

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm creating an offline phonegap build webapp.
I found a way to connect to a php file on a server when connected to the internet.

Essential code head

```
<form id="ff" action="http://localhost/coupons/addcoupon.php" method="post">
```

Essential code body

```
$('#ff').form({ 
success:function(data){ 
    $.messager.alert('Info', data, 'info'); 
} });
```

However as the webapp is offline. I'm looking for a solution to stay on the page when the php file can not be reached, and alert "Can't connect to the server!".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a handler for `error` like you do with `success` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but you should check out the docs:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
}
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

Comment: It dit not work. I guess it's because i'm working with phonegap build, and not cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jquery included you can prevent the submission of the form, check if the url is reachable and only if it is then submit the form otherwise display error message.
For example the following code,

```
var connectionExists = false;
    $('#ff').submit(function (e) {
        if (!connectionExists) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var $form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function () {
                    connectionExists = true;
                    $form.submit();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Can't connect to the server!");
                }
            });
        }


    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJuFr/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it works when i change the action to a file in the same directory as index.html. But it does not work when i change the action to http://localhost/coupons/addcoupon.php.

Comment: Are you trying this from the browser of your pc or your phone? Your phone cannot access localhost of your pc. If you are trying from pc make sure you have http://localhost or simply try absolute from root context of your application i.e.  /coupons/addcoupon.php .

Comment: I'm trying with my pc. When i go to the developers mode in firefox i can see that submitting does give a response. In fact even when i get the alert: "can't connect to the server" my php file does add a lot of rows to my database.
So i changed var url and url to a localhost test php file with just an echo.
However i think i need to set a timeout or something like that. But i don't know how.

Comment: The code actually checks if the form's url is accessible. When you are checking you do not want to run whatever it is you are running on this page. For example to achieve this you might need to add a special param to your query, so that you don't do anything just respond (not add a lot of rows to the database). A better approach would be to have a page just for checking that your server is up and running, as you did with the test.php file. You can not make cross origin requests so you must call resources that are on the same address as your php page making the check.

Comment: If your page runs under http://localhost/myapp/addcoupon.php then your url must be of the same origin i.e. "http://localhost/myapp/checkconnection.php" . This only stands for your browser when running on your phone as a hybrid app you can eliminate this restriction by specifying the hosts.